# jQuery Validate allowing submit on second click

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Still pretty new to jQuery. I'm trying to build a password change form. I want jQuery validation to stop form submission and display the required message so the user can correct the issue. What is happening is that jQuery will display messages for any issues once but then when the user doesn't fix any of the issues on the form and clicks submit a second time the form submits with the invalid data. Hoping someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Here's the code:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Change Password Form</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form class="cmxform" name="changepasswordform" id="changepasswordform"
                    method="post" action="index.php?action=changepassword">
                Current Password: 
                <input id = "currentpassword" name="currentpassword" type="password"
                        required/><br>
                New Password: 
                <input id = "newpassword" name="newpassword" type="password"
                        required/><br>
                New Password Again: 
                <input id = "newpasswordagain" name="newpasswordagain" type="password"
                        required/> <br>
                <button value="Submit" name="Submit">Submit</button>
                <button type="reset" name="Cancel">Cancel</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
```

```js
    $("#changepasswordform").validate({
        rules: {
            currentpassword: {
                required: true
            },
            newpassword: {
                noSpace: true,
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 50,
                required: true
            },
            newpasswordagain: {
                equalTo: "#newpassword",
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 50,
                noSpace: true,
                required: true
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
</script>
```

Comment: Can you share some of your code? It's hard to debug your problem without any code to debug.

Comment: That is very unusual design, but you can certainly do it by adding a simpler count value to the Javascript code.

Comment: Why would you put your JavaScript inside of `<pre>` tags?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the jQuery Validate plugin is operational on your page due to some unknown issue.  You were most likely just seeing the default [HTML5 form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation), as per the browser, since you also included the inline HTML5 `required` attribute within your input elements.

jQuery Validate is working properly with your form...

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/9vcafnL4/2/**

---

Other potential issues and notes:

1. Did you remember to include the jQuery Validate plugin someplace on the page just *after* you included jQuery?  The `.validate()` method can't work unless the plugin is included.

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
   ```
2. You are trying to use a method called `noSpace` but there is no such thing as part of the jQuery Validate plugin.  You'd have to create this method yourself or remove it.
3. Your submit button is missing the `type="submit"` attribute.
4. You don't need both the HTML5 validation attribute, `required`, along with the `required` rule defined within `.validate()`.  Since you have other validation rules, you can safely remove the `required` attribute from the input elements.
5. There is no need to redeclare all the rules on your second password field since the `equalTo` method will always ensure this value matches the first.
6. It's always a good idea to surround your jQuery within a [DOM Ready event handler function](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) to ensure that the DOM is ready before the jQuery.
7. I don't know why you've surrounded your `script` tags with [`pre` tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre), but the `pre` tags are not needed here.

Revised DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/9vcafnL4/1/

Comment: This worked great. Thanks for the help. Learned a lot from this post. I still can't get the   $("#changepasswordform").validate to work when I put it inside the $(document).ready(function (){ but it does work when I put it inside of <pre></pre> tags just below the form. I'll spend some time figuring out why my document ready function isn't doing what it's supposed to do.

Comment: @fp5885, since it contains a fully working demo of your code, please accept my answer.